# How to debug random Errno::ECONNRESET with accessing AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ssl, sidekiq

I have a background sidekiq jobs accessing files from S3 and randomly I get `Errno::ECONNRESET`. The frequency of error is around 2-3% but I cannot find a way to debug the issue.

I am using `Ruby Rails 5.1` and `aws-sdk-core 2.11.17`. I have tried updating the cert in `net_http_ssl_fix` and using my forked PR but that didn't helped either.

detailed json formatted stack trace

https://jsonformatter.org/cfd30e

```
  "extra": {
    "sidekiq": {
      "jobstr": "{\"class\":\"\",\"args\":[1637958],\"retry\":5,\"queue\":\"low\",\"backtrace\":true,\"unique\":\"until_executing\",\"log_duplicate_payload\":true,\"unique_args\":[\"\",[]],\"jid\":\"1cc963267f7c27c5d16b5f6b\",\"created_at\":1591898160.0594585,\"unique_prefix\":\"uniquejobs\",\"unique_digest\":\"uniquejobs:95d71eb08bc1f72a6808d0b5c2570d14\",\"acts_as_tenant\":{\"class\":\"Company\",\"id\":1361},\"enqueued_at\":1591898160.0606112}",
      "job": {
        "queue": "low",
        "jid": "1cc963267f7c27c5d16b5f6b",
        "acts_as_tenant": {
          "class": "Company",
          "id": 1361
        },
        "error_class": "Errno::ECONNRESET",
        "unique_prefix": "uniquejobs",
        "backtrace": true,
        "created_at": 1591898160.0594585,
        "args": [
          1637958
        ],
        "enqueued_at": 1591898160.0606112,
        "log_duplicate_payload": true,
        "unique_digest": "uniquejobs:95d71eb08bc1f72a6808d0b5c2570d14",
        "failed_at": 1591898174.849081,
        "retry_count": 0,
        "retry": 5,
        "error_message": "Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect",
        "error_backtrace": [
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `connect_nonblock'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/protocol.rb:44:in `ssl_socket_connect'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:981:in `connect'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:337:in `open_http'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'",
          "/var/app/current/app/services/test_report.rb:720:in `block in layout_pages_initialization'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:5:in `each'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/each.rb:5:in `each'",
          "/var/app/current/app/services/test_report.rb:713:in `collect'",
          "/var/app/current/app/services/test_report.rb:713:in `layout_pages_initialization'",
          "/var/app/current/app/services/test_report.rb:5:in `initialize'",
          "/var/app/current/app/workers/create_test_report_pdf.rb:58:in `new'",
          "/var/app/current/app/workers/create_test_report_pdf.rb:58:in `block in perform'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:64:in `use_zone'",
          "/var/app/current/app/workers/create_test_report_pdf.rb:53:in `perform'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:167:in `execute_job'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:139:in `block (5 levels) in process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:90:in `block in call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:89:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:135:in `block (4 levels) in process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sentry-raven-2.13.0/lib/raven/integrations/sidekiq.rb:9:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-unique-jobs-5.0.10/lib/sidekiq_unique_jobs/lock/until_executing.rb:8:in `execute'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-unique-jobs-5.0.10/lib/sidekiq_unique_jobs/server/middleware.rb:18:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-pro-3.7.1/lib/sidekiq/batch/middleware.rb:54:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:10:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/var/app/current/vendor/cache/acts_as_tenant-118aab88b67d/lib/acts_as_tenant/sidekiq.rb:21:in `block in call'",
          "/var/app/current/vendor/cache/acts_as_tenant-118aab88b67d/lib/acts_as_tenant/model_extensions.rb:56:in `with_tenant'",
          "/var/app/current/vendor/cache/acts_as_tenant-118aab88b67d/lib/acts_as_tenant/sidekiq.rb:20:in `call'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:134:in `block (3 levels) in process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:183:in `stats'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block in process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `process'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:70:in `run'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'",
          "/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.10/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:26:in `block in safe_thread'"
        ],
        "unique": "until_executing",
        "unique_args": [
          "",
          [
            1637958
          ]
        ],
        "class": ""
      },
      "context": "Job raised exception"
    },
    "server": {
      "runtime": {
        "version": "ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-linux]",
        "name": "ruby"
      },
      "os": {
        "kernel_version": "Linux UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux",
        "version": "#1 SMP Tue Feb 5 20:59:30 UTC 2019",
        "build": "4.14.97-74.72.amzn1.x86_64",
        "name": "Linux"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: any network capture file ?

Comment: I am using EC2 and there is gigs of traffic per day so I think it would be hard for me to capture the traffic and then find the event in the captured packets.

Comment: Without any material to investigate, maybe ask directly to EC2 why this happens (and they're paid for that, here we are giving help for free).

Comment: @anothermh thank you for pointing me in right direction, I have updated the question to include the stack trace in json readable format.

Comment: Are you connecting to the same bucket for every job? Or are you connecting to different buckets (and/or different owners)? Do your jobs repeat on failure? Do subsequent runs of failed jobs succeed? Are you saving your sidekiq logs somewhere that you can read them later? Can you log some identifying information about a failed job in a `rescue` somewhere, then read the logs to find commonality?

Comment: @anothermh
same bucket for every job;
yes the repeat;
subsequent runs pass 99%;
I have posted the detailed log in question;
thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: What's your concurrency in Sidekiq? Do you have APM software like New Relic installed to see transaction logs? I'm wondering if there are resource issues server-side or if you're just hammering the bucket too fast and S3 is asking you to slow down.

Comment: @anothermh thank you so much for you reply
concurrency is 16; I have aws log group and sentry.io logging failure information;
if these are resource server-side issues then I would get resource missing error ?;
as far as I know I can get limit less reads over aws ?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html